# How to get back to your activity from create app chooser?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com"});
email.setType("message/rfc822");
email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"),PICK_EMAIL_REQUEST);
```

I am using this code to allow user to contact me. It will create an app chooser. But the problem is when someone hits back button on app chooser dialog (or even from email client) it simply goes to home screen, i.e. my app is closed.

How do i get users back to my app activity?

Comment: did you override the startActivityForResult method

Comment: Yes but its not getting called while debugging when i press back button from app chooser !